# reducing recorded audio .wav file size

Tags: javascript, audio-recording, recorder.js

I am using [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/recorder.js) and [RecorderWorker.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/blob/master/recorderWorker.js) to record audio. As we know file type will be .wav and and file size is very big. I tried one solution which is got from the previous similar questions asked on stackoverflow but still for 1 min audio, file size >= 6.5 MB. Instead of both the channels I am using single channel. These are the following changes I have mad in my javascript.

In recorder.js-->

```
this.node.onaudioprocess = function(e){
      if (!recording) return;
      var buffer = [];
      for (var channel = 0; channel <1; channel++){
          buffer.push(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(channel));
      }
      worker.postMessage({
        command: 'record',
        buffer: buffer
      });
    }
```

In recorderWorker.js-->

```
function record(inputBuffer){
  for (var channel = 0; channel < 1; channel++){
    recBuffers[channel].push(inputBuffer[channel]);
  }
  recLength += inputBuffer[0].length;
}

function exportWAV(type){
  var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffers[0], recLength);
  var dataview = encodeWAV(bufferL);
  var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });
  this.postMessage(audioBlob);
}

function getBuffer(){
  var buffers = [];
  for (var channel = 0; channel < 1; channel++){
    buffers.push(mergeBuffers(recBuffers[channel], recLength));
  }
  this.postMessage(buffers);
}

function interleave(inputL, inputR){
  var length = inputL.length;
  var result = new Float32Array(length);
  var index = 0,
    inputIndex = 0;

  while (index < length){
    result[index++] = inputL[inputIndex];
    //result[index++] = inputR[inputIndex];
    inputIndex++;
  }
  return result;
}

/* channel count */
view.setUint16(22, 1, true);
/* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
  view.setUint16(32, 2, true);
```

I tried to convert it into mp3 file type using [libmp3lame.js](https://github.com/akrennmair/libmp3lame-js) but it is slow plus I can't record >2 min audio using this.

What I am asking is first, is there anything I am doing wrong because of which size is not getting reduced? Second, is there anyother way to reduce the size?

Comment: The problem is not the storage capacity. The problem is if multiple users are recording and uploading it on server at the same point then uploading may take more time as the size of file will be more.

Comment: what if you change the audioContext.sampleRate ?

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to downsize the exported `wav` file:

1. Use a single channel when initializing a new Recorder, [source](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues/172)

`rec = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:1})`

2. Or you can downsample the rate to further reduce the size, [source](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues/186)